# AVAudioRecorder averagePowerForChannel gives back invalid value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, avaudiorecorder

I recently got complains from some users: the microphone was "too sensitive" and had "significant distortion" while they were recording under iOS 10. The mic worked fine with other apps and under older OS versions.

First, I replaced the "old" core `AudioQueueRef` solution with `AVAudioRecorder`. That did not help so I tried to dig into the issue and found an interesting behaviour: the `-[AVAudioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:]` method gives back at least -52db in silent environment. If I start scratching the frame around (or blow into) the microphone, this value reached +25db!

While the Apple Docs says:

> Return Value
>
> The current average power, in decibels, for the sound being recorded.
>   A return value of 0 dB indicates full scale, or maximum power; a
>   return value of -160 dB indicates minimum power (that is, near
>   silence).
>
> If the signal provided to the audio recorder exceeds ±full scale, then
>   the return value may exceed 0 (that is, it may enter the positive
>   range).

```
static const CGFloat kSilenceDBValue = -160.0;  // based on the documentation of -[AVAudioRecorder averagePowerForChannel]


for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < ASAudioRecorderNumberOfChannels; ++i) {
    const CGFloat averageLevel = (CGFloat)[self.recorder averagePowerForChannel:i];
    const CGFloat peakLevel = (CGFloat)[self.recorder peakPowerForChannel:i];

    // Assert fires if stressing the mic 
    NSAssert1(kSilenceDBValue <= averageLevel && averageLevel <= 0.0, @"Average level has invalid value: %@", @(averageLevel));
    NSAssert1(kSilenceDBValue <= peakLevel && peakLevel <= 0.0, @"Peak level has invalid value: %@", @(peakLevel));

    ...
}
```

I also set up a [**demo project** here](https://github.com/AdamStreet/recording-test).

The value itself could be balanced with a(n exponential) function, but should it be?
Is there anything I missed on the configuration so I am getting this high average power value?

Thanks